# How to hot deploy web application on remote weblogic server?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, weblogic

I'm working on a java spring web application. Every time I have a little change in application, there is no way for publish this change in weblogic except creating war file and deploy it to the server. I'm working on eclipse and I want to apply changes on live project in remote server(say 192.168.0.74 while I'm on 192.168.0.70). Is there any plugin or easy solution for this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Eclipse development with WebLogic, install the Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse to better integrate with WebLogic. You can then deploy to a remote server automatically.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Worked nicely. Thanks.